# SAML Request-Response Handeling in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: encoding, single-sign-on, saml, opensaml, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 For Single Sign On Purpose.
In my web application(Service Provider), I am writing my own custom implementation for **SAML Request-Response** handling using **OpenSAML**.

I want to know that which other encoding formats are supported by WSO2 IS 5.0 as I have seen **BASE64** **Encoding** in one of the examples given by WSO2.
This information will be useful for handling marshaling and unmarshalling Issues.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity servers SAML implementation is adhere to SAML specifications. So it support the encoding mechanisms defined in SAML Binding specification [1]
At the moment HTTP-Redirect and HTTP- Post bindings are supported 
HTTP-Redirect : DEFLATE Encoding
HTTP-Post : BASE64 Encoding 
is used

[1]https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35387/sstc-saml-bindings-errata-2.0-wd-05-diff.pdf